# TYPO3 merge list and edit

Tags: typo3, fluid

I've got a TYPO3 backend module which lists a lot of elements. Now, I want to include in my list the edit form, but that doesn't work well at the moment.

Rendering is good, but if I send the form, I get the error:

`Required argument "note" is not set.`

My code looks like this:

```
<f:for each="{notes}" as="note">
  <f:form action="update" name="note" object="{note}">
    <textarea class="form-control gettooltip" rows="1" placeholder="Kommentar" title="Kommentar zur Note">{note.kommentar}</textarea>
  </f:form>
</f:for>
```

How can I merge these two views correctly?

Comment: Just wondering why you don't want to use TYPO3's forms for editing records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code cannot work because your textarea doesn't have a property (or you don't use the `<f:form.textarea` ViewHelper).

If you property map $note in your controller, the property must be passed to Fluid with the prefixed extension name and plugin name. This is done automatically when using the "property" argument of the textarea ViewHelper. The name attribute will then be:

```
<textarea name="tx_myext_myplugin[note]"...
```

Thîs will map to $note in the controller.

So if you don't use the ViewHelper, you need to manually prefix the name attribute to create an output like printed just above.

If you're planning to update multiple objects of the of the same kind in one request, this won't because because there is an Extbase limitation.

You could do the following:

Use a submit button for each note and save/reload the changes through AJAX.

```
<f:for each="{notes}" as="note">
  <f:form action="update" name="note" object="{note}">
    <f:form.textarea class="form-control gettooltip" placeholder="Kommentar" property="kommentar">{note.kommentar}</f:form.textarea>
    <f:form.submit value="Update" />
  </f:form>
</f:for>
```

Then you intercept the submit click, submit the form through AJAX and set the new content to the textarea.

If you want to have one form for all objects, you will need to prefix the fields

```
<f:form action="update" name="note">
  <f:for each="{notes}" as="note">
    <f:form.textarea class="form-control gettooltip" placeholder="Kommentar" name="note[note{note.uid}][kommentar]">{note.kommentar}</f:form.textarea>
  </f:for>
  <f:form.submit value="Update" />
</f:form>
```

You will then have an array of values and need to iterate in your controller and manually persist the changes.

Comment: I have for every Note an seperate form. and send only one form for one note. with this js code.

`var uid = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.noteuid').val();
        $('#editnote' + uid).submit();`

JS is correct it selects only the selected Form.

Comment: I adjusted my answer, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem - as @lorenz answered you need to use viewhelpers for rendering fields OR at least use valid `name` attributes for your fields...

Anyway, I'm wondering why do you want to reinvent the wheel - especially while creating BE modules, the fastest, easiest and most elegant way is... using TYPO3 forms. They handle many things, relations, localization, validation, RTE etc, etc. What's more you can also add own type of field to TCA and process with your own PHP and JS - very rare situation, but may be used i.e. for adding GoogleMap field,
@see: [**`user` type in TCA**](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html)

Finally all you need to open the record from your BE module is creating proper link - which can be easily copied from List module (right click on the yellow pencil next to your record and copy the code), sample:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+T3_THIS_LOCATION+'&amp;edit[fe_users][1234]=edit'; return false;" title="Edit user">
    <span title="" class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-open">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```

Where `fe_users` is table name and `1234` is record uid.

`alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+T3_THIS_LOCATION` part handles returning to the place from which edit was started, so it will be your module again including all GET params selected by admin before editing.

For creating new user

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+T3_THIS_LOCATION+'&amp;edit[fe_users][6789]=new'; return false;" title="New record">
    <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-new">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```

In this case `6789` is a PID (uid of the page where the user should be created...

You can even set some default values when creating records from your own module using params in your new link:

`&defVals[table_name][field_name]=value`

sample

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+T3_THIS_LOCATION+'&amp;edit[fe_users][6789]=new&defVals[fe_users][tx_extbase_type]=Tx_MyExt_People&defVals[fe_users][usergroup]=1'; return false;" title="New record">
    <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-new">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```